# How can i calculate the dynamical evolution of states and a probability plot of them?

Tags: probability-or-statistics, correlation, random-process

Using 4 correlation matrices i define as my *market states* i have to follow the evolution of the market as dynamical transitions between these states. In other words, i have to show the evolution dynamics of these states. Also, i want to show the probabilistic plot of the market states dynamics.

My problem is that i can't get my head around which functions are useful for this.

This is the kind of thing i'd like to get

[image: dynamical evolution of states and probability plot]

So far, i have used `DiscreteMarkovProcess` to obtain transition probabilities using a random generated *Probability Matrix* for four states

```
mat= Transpose[Normalize[#, Total] & /@ RandomReal[1, {4, 4}]];
matpro = DiscreteMarkovProcess[1, (mat)];

plot = Graph[matpro];
Scan[(PropertyValue[{plot, #}, EdgeLabels] = PropertyValue[{plot, #}, "Probability"]) &, EdgeList[plot]]
plot
```

But i'n not sure if this is useful.

Thanks in advance for any comment.

Comment: Include some sample data? Also, isn't the problem more algorithmic than Mathematica-based? In other words, do you know the steps to achieve your goal but need to implement them, or do you not know how to get there either?

Comment: You're right. I don't know how to get there. I edited the question.